# Read HTML special characters in Delphi string

Tags: html, delphi, special-characters, decode

I have a webpage "index.html" built with Expression Web 4 containing a value delimited with an id :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<... some html code ...>
<!--MYVALUEID-->
Dernières News
<... some html code ...>
</body>
</html>
```

With my delphi application i load the page in TStringList and read the value to a TEDIT :

```
S:=TStringList.Create;
S.LoadFromFile('path\index.html');
Edit1.Text:=S[S.IndexOf('<!--MYVALUEID-->')+1];
S.Free;
```

The problem is the accent char because i got this in the TEDIT : "DerniÃ¨res News"

In Expression Web code the text is correct : Dernières News

When i open index.html in notepad it show : Dernières News

The file in notepad is shown as UTF8

When using HTTPApp.HTMLDecode() i got : DerniÃ¨res News

And with System.NetEncoding,TNetEncoding.HTML.Decode also : DerniÃ¨res News

Is there a reliable routine to decode html special char conversion ?

I checked many question in SO and tried the solutions as mentionned above but nothing happens.

Thanks in advance, i m stuck.

Comment: You are probably using Delphi 7 and so string is ANSI encoded and you take no steps to handle the UTF8. But that's just a guess. Without details guessing is all we can do.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the OP mentions `System.NetEncoding.TNetEncoding`, which didn't exist until Delphi XE7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your HTML file is encoded in UTF-8, you should specify it when calling [`LoadFromFile()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TStrings.LoadFromFile):

```
S := TStringList.Create;
S.LoadFromFile('path\index.html', TEncoding.UTF8);
```

Otherwise the ANSI encoding is used.

Comment: I just tried and got an exception "No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page" !!!

Comment: @Stalkium What version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: I am on RAD 10.3 !

Comment: @Stalkium It looks like your file is not valid UTF-8. Try doing a test with a very simple file.

Comment: I think i got it now, your solution is the simpliest and the best practise instead of Decoding and Encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UTF8ToWideString` to convert an `UTF8` string to a `unicode` string:

```
S := TStringList.Create;
try
    S.LoadFromFile('path\index.html');
    Edit1.Text := UTF8ToWideString(S[S.IndexOf('<!--MYVALUEID-->') + 1]);
finally
    S.Free;
end;
```

Comment: The OP is clearly using a Unicode version of Delphi, so the `TStringList` will be holding UTF-16 strings, not UTF-8 strings, thus calling `UTF8ToWideString()` will produce even worse results.

Comment: @RemyLebeau apparently it worked perfect, i will give several tries for other spec char before validating the answer

Comment: Of course, I had verified that my solution works before posting my answer.

Comment: @fpiette the only way `LoadFromFile()` without specifying `TEncoding.UTF8` could correctly decode a UTF-8 file containing non-ASCII characters is if the file had a UTF-8 BOM. But there is no way `UTF8ToWideString()` would work correctly, as it takes a UTF-8 encoded `RawByteString` as input, but passing it a `UnicodeString` instead will perform a runtime conversion based on the current `DefaultSystemCodePage`, which is certainly not going to be set to `CP_UTF8` by default.

Comment: @RemyLebeau To test my code before  publishing, I created a text file having this content (16 hex bytes): 44 65 72 6E 69 C3 A8 72 65 73 20 6E 6F 75 76 65 6C 6C 65 73. This is the text OP gave "Dernières nouvelles" with "è" being represented by C3 A8. I created it using Notepad++ which show "Dernières nouvelles". I loaded and displayed it like this: `S.LoadFromFile('path\index.html'); Edit1.Text := UTF8ToWideString(S[0]);`. It correctly showed the text in the TEdit. The OP confirmed that my code is working. It works for the OP.

Comment: @fpiette I don't have time or opportunity right now to verify that myself, but I can pretty much guarantee just by looking at it that the result is a fluke, not to be relied on. Without a BOM or `TEncoding.UTF8`, `LoadFromFile()` will decode that file to UTF-16 incorrectly, thus data loss occurs before `UTF8ToWideString()` is even called, and since the input to `UTF8ToWideString()` is not valid UTF-8, the result can't be depended on. Whether or not it "works" is immaterial. The logic is wrong. What you have shown can only work in pre-Unicode versions of Delphi, not in modern Unicode versions.

Answer (score -2):

I think i got the probleme but the solution lead to another problem, the file i was trying to read is "header.html" (i put index.html just for the example), and header.html will be PHP included in index file so doesn't contain any head or body info, to avoid HTML mess when included, that so for this reason it is not UTF8 encoded by Expression WEB, .... when i added a "UTF8 meta content" to the file to say to the editor to encode it, now it works.

But my problem now when i add the :

```
<head><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"></head>
```

The editor show a dialog for [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) removal request from header.html to avoid display blank space on the browser (which is true) so if i remove it the doc loose his UTF8 and if i keep it a blank space will be displayed on the browser,

I know this should be another question so i will remove the BOM and use fpiette solution to read the data.